# Advantage of Sandbox plugins in MS Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

In In MS Dynamics CRM 2011, what are the main benefit of registering plugins in Sandbox mode. When we are creating the plugin there is an option to register plugins in sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Due to Sandbox , Plug in allows in the Online Dynamics CRM.
2. Microsoft Dynamics CRM collects run-time statistics and monitors plug-ins and custom workflow activities that execute in the sandbox.
3. If the sandbox worker process that hosts this custom code exceeds threshold CPU, memory, or handle limits or is otherwise unresponsive, that process will be killed by the platform. At that point any currently executing plug-in or custom workflow activity in that worker process will fail with exceptions. However, the next time that the plug-in or custom workflow activity is executed it will run normally. There is one worker process per organization so failures in one organization will not affect another organization.

Answer (score 2):

Please read through this blog: [MS CRM 2011 Plugin Sandbox Mode Security](http://ms-crm-2011-beta.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/ms-crm-2011-plugin-sandbox-mode-security.html)

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit of Sandbox plugin is that now we can register own plugins in CRM Online. Before CRM 2011 and Sandboxing we didn't had this opportunity.